# Regex to filter and remove specific multiple lines of text from a file with python

Tags: python, regex, file, text

I'm writing a python tool to work on a set of files. This tool will be used by other users, not me.

Files are similar to the below format:

```
#Text which I want to keep intact
#Lots of text 
#Lots and lots of text 
#Lots and lots and lots of other text 

#Then in-between the file I have text in this format which I want to operate on:

ginstance 
{ 
 name ginstance_053D627B1349FA0BC57 
 node "FINDME" 
 inherit_xform on 
 visibility 255 
blah 
blah 
blah 
} 

ginstance 
{ 
 name ginstance_053D627B1349FA0BC57 
 node "DONTFINDME" 
 inherit_xform on 
 visibility 255 
blah 
blah 
blah 
}
```

What I want to do is:

1. Find these instances in the input file.
2. Check for a specific word in the instance. E.g "FINDME"
3. If the above word exists, then remove the instance from the file.
   i.e Remove text starting from "ginstance" to the squiggly bracket "}"

My tool will take this search term("FINDME") from the user using a UI.

I can find the instances I want to remove with this:

```
import re 

with open("path to input file", 'r') as input: 
    with open("path to output file", 'w') as output: 
        xfile = input.read() 
        instance = re.findall(r"ginstance.*?}", xfile, re.DOTALL) 
        for a in instance: 
            if "FINDME" in a: 
                print a
```

Additionally, this code removes all instances from input file and writes result to output:

```
data = re.sub("ginstance.*?}", "", xfile, flags=re.DOTALL)
        output.write(data)
```

But I don't want to remove all instances, just the ones with "FINDME" in it.
How can I write a single python code which include these two factors.

Hope I'm clear with the question. Thank you.

I have searched a lot on stack-overflow for this issue, and have tried out a lot of answers before posting this question.

Comment: `FINDME` is also present in `DONTFINDME`

Comment: @rock321987 Good observation. I intend to include the quotes too though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go for this approach:

```
ginstance\s*\{     # look for ginstance { literally
[^}]*              # anything not a }
(?:node\ "FINDME") # node "FINDME" literally
[^}]*              # anything not a }
\}                 # the closing }
```

It assumes, there are no other `}` in the inner block of `ginstance`.
In `Python` this would be:

```
import re   
rx = re.compile("""
        ginstance\s*\{
        [^}]*
        (?:node\ "FINDME")
        [^}]*
        \}
        """, re.VERBOSE)
string = re.sub(rx, '', your_string_here)
print string
```

See <kbd>[a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yM2lY2/1)</kbd> as well as <kbd>[on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/zngxLx)</kbd>.

#### For the opposite:

---

Taking into account your comment (to achieve the opposite), you could go for a negative lookahead solution, like so:

```
ginstance\s*\{
(?:
    [^}]
    (?!(?:node\ "FINDME"))
)+
\}
```

See a demo for this <kbd>[one on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yM2lY2/2)</kbd> as well.

Comment: Thanks. That worked well. I would like to extend my question: What if I want the inverse. Say I want to delete all instances except the "FINDME" instance from the file. i.e I can find all the instances with  re.findall but want to keep the "FINDME" instance and delete all others.

Comment: @Harshad: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ginstance.*?{.*?node\s*"FINDME".*?}
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eO9sU2/1)

Input

```
#Text which I want to keep intact
#Lots of text 
#Lots and lots of text 
#Lots and lots and lots of other text 

#Then in-between the file I have text in this format which I want to operate on:

ginstance 
{ 
 name ginstance_053D627B1349FA0BC57 
 node "FINDME" 
 inherit_xform on 
 visibility 255 
blah 
blah 
blah 
} 

ginstance 
{ 
 name ginstance_053D627B1349FA0BC57 
 node "DONTFINDME" 
 inherit_xform on 
 visibility 255 
blah 
blah 
blah 
}
```

Ouput

```
MATCH 1
1.  [194-317]   `
ginstance 
{ 
 name ginstance_053D627B1349FA0BC57 
 node "FINDME" 
 inherit_xform on 
 visibility 255 
blah 
blah 
blah 
}`
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for the regex demo website link. I accepted the other answer for better explanation but appreciate your quick answer. It was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you think `FINDME` is also present in `DONTFINDME`? That's why it is matching both of them. If its in `quotes`, then use this

```
if "\"FINDME\"" in a: 
    print a
```

or more better will be to use `re.search()`. It contains word boundary (`\b`)

```
if re.search(r"\bFINDME\b", a, re.MULTILINE): 
    print a
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of "\b". I'll remember that.

Comment: @Harshad you are welcome..glad, I could be any help for you